# Code formatting issue - adding spaces and line-wrapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resharper

On code cleanup, this:

```
<a onclick='DisplayScheduleNowPopup(@Model.Contract.ContractId, false)'>Schedule</a>
```

Turns into:

```
<a onclick=' DisplayScheduleNowPopup(@Model.Contract.ContractId, false) '>Schedule</a>
```

The spaces are added and it is causing problems. I'm using MVC Razor.

Also, on C# I would like Chop on Object Initilizer, so I have it set to chop always and it works fine. However, it turns out ridicoulous on MVC Razor.

For example: Wrap object and collection Initializer (Chop always):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateReservation", "Reservations", new
{
    temp = false
}, new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = "ReservationUpdateSucceeded",
    OnFailure = "ReservationUpdateFailed",
    LoadingElementId = "loadingDiv"
}, new
{
    id = "reservationScreenForm",
    @class = "custom form"
}))
```

Anyway to have Resharper either: ignore "Chop always" on Views.cshtml, or select "Simple Wrap" for views, while remaining "Chop Always" for C#.

Any ideas on how to solve these problems?

Comment: What version of ReSharper?

Comment: the latest version, 8.2

Comment: FWIW, I had a (unrelated) ReSharper problem this week which was in 8.2.1. I Updated to 8.2.3 and the issue was fixed. If you're not running 8.2.3 then I suggest you update; you might get lucky too.

Comment: Just updated to 8.2.3. Sadly, error still exist. Not even sure if it's an error though but Resharper adding the extra spaces after quotation has been causing problems and errors.

Comment: The adding of spaces looks like a bug to me; I can't see a good reason to do so. I recommend you search the JetBrains ReSharper discussion forum, and ask your question there if no-one has done so already. Then at least it will be on their radar.

Comment: The added spaces within the `onclick` attribute are still present and especially stupid of JetBrains. R# itself complains about the syntax which it is "cleaning up". Amazing.